# Upload of large company snapshot results in error "the file exceeds the maximal allowed size (1048576 KB)"

Tags: acumatica

Trying to upload a large Acumatica company snapshot file (1.3 GB) and I am getting an error as soon as I hit the upload button.

**What setting (if any) can I change in my local Acumatica site or web.config to allow the large file import?**

As a work around I am requesting a snapshot file without file attachments as the file attachments data is about 95% of the snapshot file size.

My file upload preferences are currently set to 25000 KB if that helps any. (I assume this setting is not used for snapshot imports.)

The error occurs after I select the file and click ok (before being able to click the upload button). I am using 2017R2 Update 4.

Image of error:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/12/restore-large-snapshot.html

Comment: awesome thanks Simon. Can you post that as the answer? I will assume that works since it was posted by Sergey. I have since received a 20MB snapshot file for the same set of data (excluding file attachments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying your web.config might work, but I think Sergey Marenich alternative is better. He  did an excellent post on his blog on how to do this.
http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/12/restore-large-snapshot.html

The idea is :

1. Get a snapshot of your site in xml
2. Extract and put the folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\Database\Data
3. Use the Configuration Wizard to deploy a site and select your snapshot data, just like you would when choosing demo data.

Answer (score 1):

If your on SaaS then you may request a copy of database and be able to restore the database for offsite instance.
If your on PCS/PCP then you have couple of options you could modify the Web.config to allow bigger files to process as detailed in this blog https://acumaticaclouderp.blogspot.com/2017/12/acumatica-snapshots-uploading-and.html

If you have larger files then you can't do it coz of IIS constraint and you can certainly use Sergey's method but that would be creating for new instance only or simple approach is to take a SQL .bak file and restore to new database.

I think Acumatica shld provide a mechanism to split these large files and have them processed into multiple uploads to accomplish but again very few customers might face this issue too.

Comment: this is a good answer too. It would be nice if there was a way to strip the file attachments automatically without needing to re-request the snapshot. I have played around with editing the snapshot file and rezip to upload and works sometimes. Not sure about removing full tables tho. Thanks for providing another alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  I tried to modify the web.config but, that gave me an error that said that the file didn't exist or I didn't have permissions when I tried to import the snapshot file into Acumatica again.

Turns out, I had a table that has image blobs stored inside of it so, it wouldn't compress.  Watch out for that one.